# How to make a simple Android app display a number after a button is pushed

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a very simple Android app based off of the first tutorial on the Android Developers site, and I have hit a snag. It's probably something really stupid, but I have code that compiles and looks good to me but doesn't do what it's supposed to. Here's my MainActivity Java. It's supposed to display your weight on Mars after you put in your weight on Earth. However, when I push my "Send" button, nothing happens.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
// Do something in response to button
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
int weight = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
double fweight = mweight(weight);
String finalmessage = Double.toString(fweight);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(finalmessage);
}
public double mweight(int eweight) {
    double mass, mars_g = 3.711;
    mass = eweight / 9.780327;
    return mass * mars_g;
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't see you setting an onclicklistener on your code. Are you defining it on your xml file? If yes, please post it.

Comment: Make a method that sets the text, and call it in the onclick of the buttom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach your new TextView to the current layout with `View#addView()` or switch the entire layout to your TextView with `Activity#setContentView()`:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(finalmessage);
setContentView(textView); // Add me!
```

To be clear this assumes that you have used `android:onClick="sendMessage"` in your Button's XML.